# Django API call taking too much time to respond

Tags: django, api, heroku, django-rest-framework, postman

I have built an API using **Django** & **django-rest-framework**. The *Django Server* is currently deployed on **Heroku**'s ***Free Hobby Dyno***.

this is how my API call looks right now,

`GET https://feasta-postgres.herokuapp.com/menu/get_category/?admin_id=5`

I am currently testing my API through **POSTMAN**.

### PROBLEM

I have noticed that when I call this API *for the **First time***, it takes *too much* (~1 second) time to respond. Then it becomes **Faster** for the **subsequent calls**. Then after **some interval** it again becomes slow.

This is the event waterfall for my first request call,
[image]

This is the event waterfall for my subsequent request calls,
[image]

As we can see in the **first image**, the ***handshakes*** are eating up most of the time.

### Questions

1. **Is there any way to optimize the first request? If yes then How?**
2. **Will this also occur when I call this *API* from a *Deployed React website* or is this only a *Postman* problem?**

### My Best Guess

I am using a **Free** Heroku Dyno, that's why **Heroku** is being **"lazy"** to *process* my request. Upgrading it to the **paid** one will do my job.

Comment: Interesting question ! I don't know if an upgrade will do the job. But for ssl handsake time, the [response of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672261/how-to-reduce-ssl-time-of-website) regroup a lot of considerations about it.

Comment: Thanks for linking that question! Turns out I was trying to send requests to the US server from India. Changing it to the EU server did the job.

Comment: That simple. And that obvious XD

Comment: Ikr! Sometimes you're looking so deep into the problem that you overlook the basic things! xD