# Automate certificate uploads into Plesk (using Selenium-IDE) not working

Tags: user-interface, ssl, upload, selenium-ide, plesk

I would like to automate the uploading of renewed certificates into different `Plesk` environments, by setting up a `Selenium-IDE` script. All is working so far, except for the upload part of the script. I understand that I somehow need to send the file to the `input` field, but would not know how to target that `input` field without the `id` -- it has no `id`!

This is what the page looks like; it is the middle *"Upload .pem file"* button that one would use to upload the file.

[image: Upload .pem file]

The code of the middle section "Upload .pem file" is:

```
<div class="ext-sslit-certificate-dropzone" style="position: relative;" multiply="false" aria-disabled="false">
  <button class="pul-button" type="button" data-test-id="ext-sslit__certificate-upload-button">
    <span class="pul-button__inner">
      <span>
        <span>Upload .pem file</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </button>
  <input accept=".pem" type="file" 
    style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; opacity: 0.00001; pointer-events: none;" 
    multiple="" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Maybe there is a way to target the `accept=".pem"` section, which is unique on the page.

Clicking on the button records:

```
command: click 
target:  css=.ext-sslit-certificate-dropzone .pul-button__inner > span > span
```

Selecting my `.pem` file records:

```
command: type
target:  css=.ext-sslit-certificate-dropzone
value:   C:\fakepath\wildcard___my_domain_name.pem
```

But playing it back it is stuck and not inserting the text into the "brows to file window" of the file I selected.

The file gets posted to a URL:

```
https://plesk.cc:8443/modules/sslit/index.php/index/upload/
```

I tired different things, but can't get it to work.

(And, why is my file location getting renamed with `C:\fakepath\`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [UI.Vision](https://ui.vision/) offers `XType` functionality, but got stuck there just as much; [link to my post on UI.Vision's support forum](https://forum.ui.vision/t/file-upload-into-plesk-for-pem-certificate-updates-has-no-id-in-input-type-file/12608) ...

**I got it working using UI.Vision.**